# Xamarin forms order draw of components

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm having a problem with the orders of the components of my main page, in this case I have her divided into three parts, Top, Boddy and Botton, Y make the search with auto complete and the component ListView Lower my boddy

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MainContext"
             Spacing="0"
             RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
             RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}" >
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnSelectMenuTapGestureTap"
                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <!-- Main manu -->
    <!-- Margin IOS-->
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="20"
                 VerticalOptions="Start"
                 BackgroundColor="#5AC8FA"/>
    <!-- end Margin IOS-->
    <StackLayout x:Name="TopBar"
                 BackgroundColor="#5AC8FA"
                 VerticalOptions="Start"
                 HeightRequest="50" 
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout x:Name="ContainerTitleLabel"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="{Binding MainMenuCmd}"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    BorderColor="Transparent"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    WidthRequest="{Binding WidthMenuRequest}"
                    HeightRequest="{Binding HeightMenuRequest}"
                    Image="icon_menu"
                    Margin="5,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="TitleLb"
                   Text="{Binding TitleLb}" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="Black"/>
            <Button HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Image="icon_search"
                    Command = "{Binding ShowSearchCmd}"
                    BorderColor="Transparent"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="ContainerSearch"
                     HorizontalOptions="Start"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     IsVisible="false">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width = "7*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width = "3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <MarkupsInterfaces:SearchBarAutoComplet Grid.Column="0"
                                                        x:Name="SearchBar"
                                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                        TextColor="White"
                                                        PlaceholderColor="White"
                                                        CancelButtonColor="Black"
                                                        Placeholder="{MarkupsInterfaces:TranslateExtension Search}">
                </MarkupsInterfaces:SearchBarAutoComplet>
                <Button Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Text="{MarkupsInterfaces:TranslateExtension Close}"
                        Command="{Binding CloseSearchCmd}"
                        FontSize="12"
                        BackgroundColor="#5AC8FA"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <!--End Main Menu -->

    <!--Boddy Context-->
    <StackLayout x:Name="Boddy"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
    </StackLayout>
    <!--End Boddy Context-->

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                 VerticalOptions="End"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <!--Botton menu navigation-->
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="Fill"
              ColumnSpacing="-5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Btn Scanner-->
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    x:Name="BtnScneer"
                    Command="{Binding ScannerTabCmd}"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Image="icon_scanner"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Margin="{Binding MarginButtons}"/>
            <!--Btn Coupons-->
            <Button Grid.Column="2"
                    x:Name="BtnCoupons"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Image="icon_coupon"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Margin="{Binding MarginButtons}"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="IndicationCoupons"
                     Grid.Column="2"
                     VerticalOptions="End"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HeightRequest="8"
                     BackgroundColor="#5AC8FA"
                     IsVisible="false"
                     Margin="5,0"/>
            <!--Btn Promotions-->
            <Button Grid.Column="3"
                    x:Name="BtnPromotions"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Image="icon_promotions"
                    Margin="{Binding MarginButtons}"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="IndicationPromotions"
                     Grid.Column="3"
                     VerticalOptions="End"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HeightRequest="8"
                     BackgroundColor="#5AC8FA"
                     IsVisible="false"
                     Margin="5,0"/>
            <!--Btn Maket car -->
            <Button Grid.Column="4"
                    x:Name="BtnMarketCar"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Image="icon_market_car"
                    Margin="{Binding MarginButtons}"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="IndicationMarketCar"
                     VerticalOptions="End"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Grid.Column="4"
                     HeightRequest="8"
                     BackgroundColor="#5AC8FA"
                     IsVisible="false"
                     Margin="5,0"/>
            <!--Btn Favorites-->
            <Button Grid.Column="5"
                    x:Name="BtnFavorites"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Image="icon_favorite"
                    Margin="{Binding MarginButtons}"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="IndicationFavorites"
                     Grid.Column="5"
                     VerticalOptions="End"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HeightRequest="8"
                     BackgroundColor="#5AC8FA"
                     IsVisible="false"
                     Margin="5,0"/>
        </Grid>
    <!--End bottom menu navigation-->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

[the content of body is dynamic, and my problen is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r725a.png)

As a possibility to force the top to always be on the whole context